# How to avoid extra space while inserting data into database

Tags: php

Hi I have 2 environments, PROD and DEV

In DEV we are using:

```
1 x apache server (FE)
1 x mysql (BE) -8
PHP version : 7.3
```

PROD Environment:

```
1 x NGINX (FE)
1 x mysql (BE) 8 
PHP Version 7.3
```

When I execute

Objectives :

Technical : execute the syntax without entering all the fields 
technical -Performance : by entering all the unused fields, it is acquiring 30 additonal bytes which i would like to reduce.

Alternatives :

By adding all the unused fields taking extra space how to avoid extra space,
example: i have 7 fields in a table, but i want to insert 3 fields only in but in order to insert it is except all fields to fill which takes extra space.
I am trying which not able to insert:

```
insert into emp(usrname, usrid) values('$usrname'.'$usrid');
```

which is working, but I don't want an extra field

```
insert into emp(usrname, usrid, location) values('$usrname','$usrid',' ');
```

Comment: why you inserting less values & giving more column names???

Comment: need that field for feature proofing, i am going to update location field in another module but not while inserting

Comment: You have wrong table design, try to normalize your single table to multiple table with one to one  or one to many relationship. Share your table DDL, will try to help you

Comment: Hi,
thank you Engr, i will outline the desing below, please help me in validing and advise me.

Table Design : 
 Total number of tables : 20 
   Heavy tables (13) have : 30 fields 
   Medium tables have (7) : 5 fields on an average
 Normalisation: Yes , used only 1NF and 2NF.


Live scenario: 

We are providing user with 3 different forms to fill user information. We are using a single sql record to capture (Insert & Update) the information.

Comment: Table Design used : 
Number of fields : 20 
Normalisation : yes 1NF and 2NF.
Form 1 requires : only 3 fields out of 20
FOrm 2 requires : 7 fields out of 20
Form 3 requires : 10 fields out of 20

Steps : 
 a. user fills form 1 on day 1 
 b. user fills form 2 after 2 days
 c. user skips filling form 3 .


Question / challenge is: 

I am forced to declare all 20 fields for form 1 during inserting or creating a new record. 
please advise.